# ordering a recursive tree parse in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following sheet of data:
https://ethercalc.org/gdxj6z5njeg3

I have code which can generate this desired tree:

```
Root
  Lima
    Delta
    Echo
      Foxtrot
      Golf
      Hotel
      India
      Juliett
      Kilo
  Mike
  November
  Oscar
    Papa
      Alpha
      Bravo
      Charlie
    Quebec
```

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub newlist()
    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
    Dim num_rows
    Dim parent As Range, parentName As String
    Dim parentRange As Range, childrenRange As Range
    Dim childCount As Long
    Dim p As Variant

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set w1 = Sheets("Sheet6")
    num_rows = w1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    'If there's no parentName column, we can't continue.
    If w1.Rows(1).Find("parentName") Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set parentRange = w1.Rows(1).Find("parentName").Offset(1).Resize(num_rows - 1, 1)
    'If there's no Root level, how do we know where to start?
    If parentRange.Find("Root") Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For Each parent In parentRange
        If Not dict.Exists(parent.Value) Then
            childCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(parentRange, parent.Value)
            Set childrenRange = parent.Offset(, 2).Resize(childCount, 1)
            dict.Add parent.Value, Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(childrenRange.Value))
        End If
    Next
    Set w2 = Sheets.Add
    ' Recursive method to traverse our dictionary, beginning at Root element.
    Call ProcessItem("Root", dict, w2, 2)

    w2.Cells(1, 1).Value = w1.Cells(1, 8).Value
    w2.Cells(1, 2).Value = w1.Cells(1, 10).Value

End Sub
Private Sub ProcessItem(name As String, dict As Object, ws As Worksheet, row_num As Long, Optional indent As Long = 0)
Dim output As String, v
' add spaces to indent the output string:
output = WorksheetFunction.Rept(" ", indent) & name
Debug.Print output
' write output to the new worksheet:
ws.Cells(row_num, 1).Value = output
row_num = row_num + 1
If Not dict.Exists(name) Then
    'we're at a terminal element, a child with no children.
    Exit Sub
Else
    For Each v In dict(name)
        ' ## RECURSION ##
        Call ProcessItem(CStr(v), dict, ws, row_num, indent + 2)
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

The question, is whether or not a logic can be implemented to order this recursive output. For instance, if I want the order of my Root-children to be: [Mike, November, Lima, Oscar], is it possible to do this within my code?

Comment: So a custom order?

Comment: A recursive function is not much more than a function that calls itself.

Comment: You'll need to somehow associate/map "Mike" to index 0, "Lima" to index 1, "Oscar" to index 2, and so on - and then lookup the sort-index of the value you're looking at and use that for your sorting.

Comment: @QHarr yes, a hardcoded custom order, and I'm not sure how the logic works.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon, can this be done during the recursive printing? I'm don't quite understand how you can put a subtree your currently on "off" temporarily if it's not in the order you want.